# Excel 16.43 - cut a row, then attempt to FIND where you need to paste it. The FIND dialog appears disabled till you cancel the CUT

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to move a few rows around a large sheet, though if I select a row, CUT it (<CTRL/CMD>+X ), then attempt to FIND where it needs to go, to save much scrolling. I find the FIND dialog appears to be disabled while a row is on the clipboard.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

While some text is selected / on the clipboard the FIND dialog is now, by default, limited to finding within the copied / cut SELECTION. Though it you change the context of the find from "Within: SHEET to WORKBOOK", the find operation will work more of less as expected (Oh for a "Within: Selection, Sheet, Workbook" dropdown).